# Windows 7 compatible improvements for .net 4.5.1

Tags: .net, .net-4.5

If I build enterprise WPF apps for desktop on **Windows 7**, is there much in .net 4.5.1 for me?

If we don't currently (and don't plan any time soon) to support any Windows 8 stuff, is it worth trying to get my company to upgrade to 4.5.1?

NOTE: I am not referring to VS 2013 (which includes 4.5.1), but the actual .NET 4.5.1 runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are significant improvements.  See the [What's New](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  page on MSDN for details.

That being said, as an enterprise developer, the improvements to [EventSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are fairly significant.  There are also significant performance improvements related to JIT and startup time.